# Is stimming only limited to people with autism or other disabilities or do neurotypical people stim as well? Is stimming always a symptom?

Tags: stress, autism, anxiety, stimulation

I've been diagnosed with anxiety. I tend to do certain things when I'm nervous or stressed. Like tap my foot. Just two years ago, I've started biting myself when I think of stressful situations or have painful memories. Is this normal?

Comment: Do you guys know a stack exchange that can help me answer this?